# Excel OFFSET and IFERROR in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in excel with two columns [RunningTotal] and [Change].

I have a formula like this for [RunningTotal]

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET([@RunningTotal];-1;0);100)+[@Change]
```

Its a table with two columns, one for a running total and the other for the change. The IFERROR is for the first row since it cannot be offset because there are no rows before it.

My table looks like this.

```
3 , #VALUE!
4 , 104
2 , 106
5 , 111
etc...
```

First row throws a error, the second row to reference the first row produce an error but then fallback's to the value `100 + change`. 
Have i done something wrong?

Comment: IFERROR(IFERROR(OFFSET([@RunningTotal];-1;0);100)+[@Change];100) seems to give the expected result. Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you are accessing the cell one above the top of the tables's data body. It is the header string value (e.g. *RunningTotal*) and you receive the #VALUE! error when you try to use the string mathematically with the @Change number.

However, the SUM of a string is zero so that could be checked for.

```
=IF(SUM(OFFSET([@RunningTotal], -1, -1, 1, 2)), OFFSET([@RunningTotal], -1, 0), 100)+[@Change]
```

That formula checks that the row being examined will SUM to zero for both @Change and @RunningTotal.

[image: Table Column References]

After rereading your original formula it has occurred to me that you could also use your original if you brought the `+[@Change]` into the error evaluation.

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET([@RunningTotal], -1, 0)+[@Change], 100+[@Change])
```

Comment: Thank you! this makes perfect sense since i encountered my cells being filled with the actual header text if i didnt add in the Change column!.